# IntelliJ/WebStorm File search with Dart

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, webstorm

The following line of Dart code shows true for existing files when run from the Terminal but false when run from IntelliJ or WebStorm. Can someone explain why and how to set up Idea editors so that it will return the same results as the Terminal run.

```dart
bool pathExists(String path) => new File(path).existsSync();
```

**Update**

After tinkering I've now found out that if I create the project in WebStorm 5 using 'open directory' it works fine for all(WebStorm, IntelliJ, and the Terminal). <strike>The problem is when I try to create the project in IntelliJ 12 as there seems to be no equivalent to open directory it seems to try to create a Java project. WebStorm seems to have better support for creating a Dart application from scratch at the moment.</strike> **See answers below for instructions.**

Comment: Creating a project with the **Web** module type should have the same effect as open directory in WebStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should show the whole program *and* how you run it, otherwise I can only guess. And my guess would be that you are passing a *relative* path to the function and you run the program from a different directory than IntelliJ.

Let's say I have this Dart program:

```
import 'dart:io';

bool pathExists(String path) => new File(path).existsSync();

main() {
  print(pathExists('books.txt'));
}
```

This program will print `true` when the `books.txt` file exists **in the current directory**. I happen to have such file in my home directory, so when I do

```
ladicek@argondie:~$ dart check_file.dart
```

it will obviously print `true`. But if I run *the same program* from another directory, it will surely print `false`. And that's probably what happens in your case.

You should check the *Run/Debug Configuration* in IntelliJ, it lets you configure the directory where the program is started.

Comment: Thanks, I'm updating the original post as I've found the problem but not the solution. I'm unable to get the adjust the configurations to get this to work in IntelliJ but I am in WebStorm if I originally create it in WebStorm. For the moment I create the project in WebStorm and then open it in IntelliJ after.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I'm adding an answer below detailing how to create a Dart project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Following @CrazyCoder's comment: Selecting

> Create New Project

then

> Static Web/Web Module

and choose your folder at

> Project Location

then expand

> More Settings

and finally make sure that

> Module File Location

is set to where your main() dart file is located. By default it is set to the content root.

Has the same effect as *Open Directory*. I've tried it and it works fine.